# Closure Compiler warning - HTMLCanvasElement and Element types mismatch

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I am not sure how to clear this warning:

```
WARNING - actual parameter 1 of    
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImage does not match formal parameter

found   : Element
required: (HTMLCanvasElement|HTMLImageElement|HTMLVideoElement|null)

ctx.drawImage( poolCanvas, rect.x, rect.y );
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
var /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement|Element} */ poolCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

var /** @type {CanvasRenderingContext2D} */ ctx;

...

ctx.drawImage( poolCanvas, rect.x, rect.y );
```

I have tried a various combination of type declarations and I can't get rid of this warning.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to type cast the call to `document.createElement`:

```
var poolCanvas = 
    /** @type {!HTMLCanvasElement} */ (document.createElement('canvas'));
```

*Note the extra parens - they are required for a type cast*